# Besides the Chinese and Western Zodiacs, are there other folk traditions with a different set of creatures?

Tags: comparative, animals

I'm a writer working in a book and I need a set of creatures for a fantasy book. To give you an idea of what I intend I already use the animal signs of the Chinese Zodiac in an idea with each one corresponding to a different god of a different pantheon, another idea handles the twelve signs of the Western Zodiac but with monsters that a heroe needs to fight, and another uses the 12 animals of Xinyiquan for another idea.

But, I still one more set. Are there any traditions with a like the above, that numbers more than 7?

Comment: Wikipedia has a long list that could help and it's grouped by various categories https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_by_type Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Wait, are you looking the any random seven creatures, or a group of seven?

Comment: Preferably a group of seven (or any other number) that is not random

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of right now are several groups of female deities that appear in various Indo-European mythologies.

The best-known ones are the nine [Muses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muses) and the seven [Pleiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades_(Greek_mythology)) from Greek Mythology. But there are also the [nine daughters of Ægir and Rán](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Daughters_of_%C3%86gir_and_R%C3%A1n) in Norse myth, and the seven daughters of the Sea of Irish folklore. These last ones are rather obscure Irish goddesses who are invoked in an incantation (translated [here](https://www.maryjones.us/ctexts/cetnad-e.html)).

Comment: Interesting, I would check on that